# --localize-symbol does not work on windows with mingw-w64

Tags: c, mingw-w64, objcopy

I have two files

**foo_var.c**

```c
int global_var = 1;
```

**foo_print.c**

```c
#include <stdio.h>

extern int global_var;

void print_foo(void)
{
    printf("print_foo = %d\n", global_var);
}
```

that compile and link into foo.o and localize global_var

```
gcc -c foo.c foo_print.c
ld -r -o foo.o foo_print.o foo_var.o
objcopy -L global_var foo.o
```

And two files

**bar_var.c**

```c
int global_var = 2;
```

**bar_print.c**

```c
#include <stdio.h>

extern int global_var;

void print_bar(void)
{
    printf("print_bar = %d\n", global_var);
}
```

compile and link into bar.o and localize global_var too

```
gcc -c bar.c bar_print.c
ld -r -o bar.o bar_print.o bar_var.o
objcopy -L global_var bar.o
```

also I have `main`, where I call `print_foo` and `print_bar`

**main.c**

```c
void print_foo(void);
void print_bar(void);

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    print_foo();
    print_bar();

    return 0;
}
```

When I compile and link all together

```
gcc -c main.c
gcc main.o foo.o bar.o
```

and run `a.exe` I get this

```
print_foo = 1
print_bar = 1
```

instead

```
print_foo = 1
print_bar = 2
```

How localize symbols in mingw-w64 correctly?

gcc version 12.2.0 (x86_64-win32-seh-rev2, Built by MinGW-W64 project)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

localization global_var symbol is not enough, because foo.o (and bar.o) have another symbol .refptr.global_var and it also needs localization

```
    objcopy -L global_var -L .refptr.global_var foo.o
    objcopy -L global_var -L .refptr.global_var bar.o
```

but this approach leads to a broken a.exe with unresolved links (without warning and errors from gcc and ld!)

```
    U .refptr.global_var
```

then in the foo.o I found the symbol .rdata$.refptr.global_var, redefined it

```
    objcopy -L global_var -L .refptr.global_var --redefine-sym .rdata$.refptr.global_var=.rdata$.refptr.foo_global_var foo.o
    objcopy -L global_var -L .refptr.global_var --redefine-sym .rdata$.refptr.global_var=.rdata$.refptr.bar_global_var bar.o
```

and got a warning from ld:

```
    ld: foo.o: warning: COMDAT symbol '.rdata$.refptr.foo_global_var' does not match section name '.rdata$.refptr.global_var'
```

that gave me an idea to redefine section .rdata$.refptr.global_var in a similar way

```
    objcopy -L global_var -L .refptr.global_var --redefine-sym .rdata$.refptr.global_var=.rdata$.refptr.foo_global_var --rename-section .rdata$.refptr.global_var=.rdata$.refptr.foo_global_var foo.o
    objcopy -L global_var -L .refptr.global_var --redefine-sym .rdata$.refptr.global_var=.rdata$.refptr.bar_global_var --rename-section .rdata$.refptr.global_var=.rdata$.refptr.bar_global_var bar.o
```

finally it worked, but shouldn't objcopy do it itself?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).